# EF Core how to map table names to Entity names, not DbSet names?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0, ef-core-5.0

I see the CodeFirst in EF Core generates the table names from the DbSet names of the DbContext.

If I have `DbSet<Person> People {get; set;}` I will get the `People` as table name for `Person`, however I would like it to be `Person`.

I tried [this solution](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/167), but it seems it not for the Core...

After that I tried

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
                
    foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity(entity.Name)
            .ToTable(entity.Name);
    }
}
```

This is better, but it gives me the full name of the class with the namespace, is there a way to remove the namespace from it?

Answer (score 2):

You can also [annotate your class](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/table-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) with an attribute specifying your desired table name. This is extremely useful when you follow a specific pattern of table names:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace YourProject.YourPackage
{
    [Table("tblPerson")]//this is how the table will be called in the database. You can also specify a schema if needed
    public class Person
    {
        //your properties here
    }
}
```

Comment: When a field name is specified using DbSet, it does not work. https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#table-name

Answer (score 1):

Use `DisplayName()` instead of `Name`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
                
    foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity(entity.Name)
            .ToTable(entity.DisplayName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using this approach and found it failed when there was a many to many relationship in the DbContext. Ef Core would create an internal entity to do the many-to-many join and that would error out on the above code.

In order to over come that I changed the code to below. *Warning*: This uses EF Core internal API and may break in the future as EF Core evolves

```cs
        foreach (EntityType entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            if (!entity.IsImplicitlyCreatedJoinEntityType)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity(entity.ClrType).ToTable(entity.ClrType.Name);
            }
        }
```